# Routing for HTTP Get without arguments doesn't work (web.api)

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api

Peculiar situation, I have this method

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/models/getallmachines")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllMachines()
    {
        var model= db.machine.ToList();
        return Ok(model);
    }
```

And I always get that the resource was not found when calling `http://localhost:xxx/api/models/getallmachines`. But if I add an argument, say

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/models/getallmachines/{blub}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAllMachines(int blub)
    {
        var model= db.machine.ToList();
        return Ok(model);
    }
```

It works with `http://localhost:xxx/api/models/getallmachines/0`! Why? This is my webapiconfig

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Using route debugger in the browser I get [image: see image below]

There is another method in the same controller, this one here

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/models/getmodel/{id}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetModel(int id)
    {
        var model = models.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ApiModelId == id);
        if (model == null)
            return NotFound();
        return Ok(model);
    }
```

Which gives me the json file in the browser and this route debugger information

[image]

Comment: What happens if you change routeTemplate to: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}". Then getallmachines would be mapped as the action. I suspect that it might be interpreted as id right now (maybe).

Comment: Nope, that wasn't it, unfortunately

Comment: what happens with an attribute `RoutePrefix("api/models")` on your controller class and an attribute `Route("getallmachines")` on your method

Comment: Same issue, doesn't work

Comment: What is the result code 404 or 403?

Comment: The result is 404

Comment: Ah! sorry! i did not see that `api` was your root. So with `RoutePrefix("models")` and `Route("getallmachines")` it will work. It works with an argument due to your `MapHttpRoute` in your config and not due to your attribute. You can remove `MapHttpRoute` in your config

Comment: @RobertStettler check to make sure that there is not a route conflict with any other route that may have the same mapping. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. What you have shown should work so that mean that there is something else causing the problem which was not shown in the original question.

Comment: @Troopers removing the `MapHttpRoute` didn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is - as so often - very stupid... I forgot to mention, that I'm using web.api as well as *regular mvc*. In the `Global.asax.cs`, the mvc routes were initialized first, then those for web.api, i.e.

```
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

instead of

```
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

That caused, that the pattern `api/models/whatever` is matched by the default route config in mvc, i.e.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

so changing the order of the calls in  `Global.asax.cs` solved the issue. Thanks @Joshit

Comment: Great! Glad that I was able to help :) Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

I think you can add a new Route to your RouteConfig.

```
       `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApiWithoutId",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/",
            defaults: null
        );`
```

This route should be placed after the first route (because its less restrictive). Here is a description for a nice package, which makes it easier to check, which routes get taken and why: [Route Debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx/).

**NOTE:** Before you release something, you MUST uninstall/disable routedebugger.. Can cause annoying problems...

Comment: Didn't work, but check out the updated question for more info about the route debugger.

Comment: Your error page seems to contain part of the problem: ASP maps your controller to api, your action to models and your id to getAllMachines. As I see you question, this is not the expected behaviour.. I´d recommend, that you first try to match your url to exactly your expected result...

Comment: And one more thing: The route-debugger lists the matching routes ordered by the calls, from ASP. The order of the routes matters!!! You should add the above route BEFORE the route with Id...

Comment: I found the problem, very stupid, but your comment about *before* gave me the right hint, thank you.